# Jenkins can't start maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to start maven via jenkins on a windows machine. Now I created the job and choose the maven goals option. I inserted "test" as the goal and gave it the destination to the pom.xml file. But now when I start the job it sais it doesnt recognise the command "mvn". When I type this into my command line it works just fine! Can anybody tell me please what im doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is Maven installed and available on the PATH of the Jenkins agent?

Comment: Jenkins can install Maven itself.

Comment: I added the M2_HOME and the MAVEN_HOME Systemvariables which both are "C:\maven". And I installed Jenkins to C:\jenkins.

Comment: Configure Maven in Global Tools configuration of Jenkins and don't use systemvariables for such things..Apart from that M2_HOME is obsolete and not supported anymore by [Maven since 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html).